# Sort elements vanila js

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I want sort my DOM elements.
This is my code

```js
function sortP() {
var p = document.body.getElementsByTagName('p');
    Array.from(p)
        .sort((a, b) => a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent))
        .forEach(p => document.body.insertBefore(p, sort))
}

document.getElementById("sort").addEventListener('click', sortP)
```

```html
  <div id="list">
      <div><p>foo</p> <span>lorem abc</span></div>
      <div><p>baz</p><span>lorem lorem abc</span></div>
      <div><p>bar</p><span>lorem lorem loremabc</span></div>

    </div>

<button id="sort">sort</button>
```

Results:

> lorem abc
>
> lorem lorem abc
>
> lorem lorem lorem abc
>
> bar
>
> baz
>
> foo

However, I would like them to sort in the following way

```
bar
lorem abc

baz
lorem lorem abc

foo
lorem lorem lorem abc
```

I do not know how to fix the code to get the correct result ( I want to sort only the element p.)

Comment: Getting the right result here

Comment: For the result you want it looks like you want to sort the `div` children of `#query` according to their `p` text.

Comment: @ellipsi No, beceuse I want to sort only the p element

Comment: @Doe then please change what is in the `span` elements because it is not clear at the moment.

Comment: @Doe my upvote please :p

Comment: @GauravSaraswat I aded, thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost correct in comparing and sorting but you should select the whole block to be moved  ie. selector Item should be like `<div><p>foo</p> <span>lorem abc</span></div>`

```js
function sortP() {
  let blocksList = document.body.querySelectorAll('#list > div');
  blocksList = Array.from(blocksList);

  blocksList.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.querySelector('p')
      .textContent.localeCompare(
        b.querySelector('p').textContent
      );
  })
  .forEach(p => document.body.insertBefore(p, sort));
}

document.getElementById("sort").addEventListener('click', sortP);
```

```html
<div id="list">
      <div><p>foo</p> <span>lorem abc</span></div>
      <div><p>baz</p><span>lorem lorem abc</span></div>
      <div><p>bar</p><span>lorem lorem loremabc</span></div>

    </div>

<button id="sort">sort</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get div element instead of p element

```js
function sortP() {
var p = document.body.getElementsByTagName('div');
    Array.from(p)
        .sort((a, b) => a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent))
        .forEach(p => document.body.insertBefore(p, sort))
}

document.getElementById("sort").addEventListener('click', sortP)
```

```html
  <div id="list">
      <div><p>foo</p> <span>abc</span></div>
      <div><p>baz</p><span>abc</span></div>
      <div><p>bar</p><span>abc</span></div>

    </div>

<button id="sort">sort</button>
```

Comment: @ellipsis it is working I guess have you tried this ?